# Upload multiple file with Ajax jQuery Using JSON/Form data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to upload file within multiple objects. I am able to upload single file or multiple file using form data.

Below sample is working fine.

```
var form_data = new FormData();
form_data.Append("test","test")
form_data.Append("test","test")
form_data.Append("file",file)
form_data.Append("file1",file1)
```

My issue is that how to upload data like this.

```
var obj = {
           "field1":"test",
           "field2","test", 
           "childObj": [
               {"filed1:"test","field2":"test","file":file},
               {"filed1:"test","field2":"test","file":file},
               {"filed1:"test","field2":"test","file":file}
            }]
          }
```

here child object is dynamically added using jQuery. so it is n number of children and every child contains one file that will be uploaded by HTML input tag file.

I want to upload this JSON data using Ajax.

Comment: Did you as a user actively allow the browser to load your file during your test?

Comment: You can't put file uploads in JSON.

Comment: @barmar is there any alternet way to upload json like this?

Comment: @lajosarpad my requirement is that I want to upload data with one parent record and other records are child with detail and file.

Comment: @PravinTukadiya yes, that's understood. But you will not be able to upload a file without the user wanting it. Imagine a case when you are opening a page and that page, without your consent would simply upload some files from your filesystem. Of course this is extreme security concern and browsers do not support this. So, I'm asking the question again: did you, as a user actively upload your file during your test?

Comment: @LajosArpad I understand what are you saying. I need to save records with multiple document with document meta data. And here User Input is required for upload. user need to upload files and user will fill the require data.

Comment: Yes, this exactly correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a file upload inside JSON. You should send the JSON in a separate parameter.

```
let obj = {
  "field1":"test",
  "field2","test", 
  "childObj": [
     {"field1":"test","field2":"test"},
     {"field1":"test","field2":"test"},
     {"filed1":"test","field2":"test"}
  }]
};

let form_data = new FormData();
form_data.append("obj", JSON.stringify(obj));
form_data.Append("file", file);
form_data.Append("file1", file1);
```